# Parsing the output of date with sed

Tags: shell, sed, date

I am trying to replace the whitespaces in the output of date with '_' with no success.

```
$date
Fri Sep 14 14:10:04 EDT 2012

$ date | sed 's/ /_/'
Fri_Sep 14 14:10:24 EDT 2012
```

As you can see, the last command only replaced the first whitespace by a `_`'. Why did it skip the other whitespaces?

Comment: Most versions of `date` let you specify the format directly instead so you DON'T have to massage it later with other tools.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try:

```
$ date | tr ' ' '_'
```

or

```
$ date | sed 's/ /_/g'
```

Your command only replaced the first matching instance from the date input because that is the default behaviour of `sed`. By adding the `g` (global replacement) option to the end of the command, `sed` will instead match and replace all occurrences of the expression.

Comment: In a case like this, `tr` is faster than a regexp substitution.

Answer (score 6):

Just my 2 cents. If you want a date as a single word, a good format is the [ISO 8601 standard](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) 2012-09-14T21:08:12. It is terse, unambiguous, and its chronological order is the same as its alphabetical order.

```
date +%Y-%m-%dT%T
```

which on some systems you may even write as

```
date +%FT%T
```

Beware though that in time zones that implement DSTs, that's still ambiguous. Adding `%z` removes the ambiguity, but doesn't help with sorting. Another option is to display the UTC time (with `-u`) or the Unix epoch time (`%s` is some implementations) which is independent of time zones.